# IBM Integration Bus and xsd:anyType

Tags: messagebroker

I'm working with IIB v9 mxsd message definitions. I'd like to define one of the XML elements to be of type xsd:anyType. However, in the list of types I can choose from, only anySimpleType and anyUri are possible (besides all other types like string, integer, etc.).

How can I get around this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XMLNSC parser supports the entire XML Schema specification, including xs:any and xs:anyType. In IIBv9 you should create a Library and import your xsds into it. Link your Application to the Library and the XMLNSC parser will find and use the model. You do not need to specify the name of the Library in the node properties; the XSD model will be automatically available to the entire application.

You do not need to use a message set at all in IIBv9 and later versions.
The mxsd file format is used only by the MRM (not DFDL) parser.

Comment: But then how do I make a mapping? It looks like I need the mxsd.

Comment: A message set is one type of message model.

Comment: A library that contains xsds is another type of model. Both can be used in the Mapping node.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an MXSD to model your XML data, use a normal XSD.

MXSD is for modelling data for the DFDL parser, but you should use the XMLNSC parser for XML messages and define them in XSDs, in which you can use anyType.

As far as I know DFDL doesn't support anyType.